# Is it possible to Inject Mocks in Static class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have static class. I am writing JUnit for one of the static method using Junit and Mockito. In that method other class level static variable's function is called. I want to mock this function call. My code is as follows,

```
class ABC {
    public static SomeVariable var;

    public static Value getSomething() {
        try {
            Value val = var.getValue();
        }
        catch (Probable exceptions) { //Handle exceptions } 
        }
    }
}
```

In Junit I have written following to inject mock,

```
@Mock
SomeVariable var;

@InjectMocks
ABC abcTest;

Mockito.when(var.getValue()).thenReturn(somevalue); //Getting compilation error here 
abcTest.getSomething();
```

While mocking var.getValue() I am getting error as 'Unhandled Exception type'
Please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you double check your example code; it has issues, but the compilation error you mention in the comment is not one of them

Answer (score 0):

I have also been struggling with trying to mock static methods before. I have no direct solution to the problem, because I solved it in a different way. I removed the static part because it was causing to much problem when I wrote my tests.

But my suggestion is to look at [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) for mocking static methods.
Maybe that's interesting in your case.